# How do Ruby Gems Load in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have a ruby gem that I want to use, but it's use is only needed in one model or controller.

Is there a way to load that gem exclusively for that one model or controller?

Would it be a waste of resources for it to be available systemwide (callable from any controller)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer posted is incorrect, it's perfectly possible to only load a gem for a particular model or controller. Your Gemfile allows you to define **groups** that Bundler can use to require certain gems. By default, any ungrouped gems along with the gems for the environment you are currently running in are required, and any named groups are not required. So if you had the following Gemfile:

```
gem 'always_used_gem', '1.0.0'

group :rarely_used do
  gem 'rarely_used_gem', '1.0.0'
end
```

Then `rarely_used_gem` would not be required on initial application load. If you had a particular method that needed that functionality, you could do this:

```
def do_stuff
  Bundler.require :rarely_used
  # use stuff from rarely_used_gem
end
```

One note: make sure the Bundler.require is inside a method call or something like that, or else the group will be required when the file is parsed (i.e. application boot)

In terms of whether you want to do this, it should really only be used for exceptional circumstances. You're trading boot speed for execution speed by doing this, which might make sense in development but probably doesn't in production. Also, you can use this method if you have some incompatibilities between two gems (we use this to resolve issues between a couple of AWS gems, for instance.)

Comment: i'm thinking of this for if i ever create "heavy" gems that do something pretty unusual but very rarely, i would want that functionality to be only available in one place.

Comment: Uh, no. Once a gem is loaded it's loaded until the server is stopped. By doing what you show, the first time this method is called it would load the gem, winding the app up in the same situation as if you were to load it normally. You're going the long way about it.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible. Once a gem has been loaded it will be available for all controllers / models / everything. This should not be a primary concern for you. RAM and CPU time is cheap, programmer's time is not.

Comment: does that mean all the gems are loaded somewhere in middleware?

Comment: @Joseph Gems are loaded prior to rack I think.

Answer (score 0):

Bundler autoloads/-requires all gems, unless

```
#Gemfile
gem :somegem, :require => false
```

Then you can do require it when you need it

```
#some_ruby_file.rb
#within_some_context 
require 'somegem'
```

How useful it is and when to do this (except for when the load order is important, as for the mocha gem (needed to be loaded last)), I don't know. I leave this to your own judgement.